# Create trigger syntax error while inserting for trigger action

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger such that if there is any change in a particular table column then event should be created in another. I am using following sql query for this

```
CREATE TRIGGER enabled_update BEFORE UPDATE ON useraccount 
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.enabledAccount != OLD.enabledAccount) THEN
       INSERT INTO logEvents
       SET NEW.event = OLD.employeeID;
    END IF;
END;
```

But I am getting following error when I am trying to run this query.
*Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '' at line 6* and  *Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'END IF' at line 1*. Where I am mistake?

Comment: The insertion query is not complete, its missing some clauses and a semi-column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DELIMITER` command, see [23.1 Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `enabled_update`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `enabled_update`
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `useraccount`
FOR EACH ROW     
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.`enabledAccount` != OLD.`enabledAccount`) THEN
       INSERT INTO `logEvents`
       SET `event` = OLD.`employeeID`;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```